# how to remove the blank lines in a csv python

Tags: python, xml, csv, space

here is my code and im getting 'TypeError: newline is an invalid argument'

i have converted a xml file to csv and now i want the output file to be without blank spaces in between each line.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("stores.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

stores = open('stores.csv','w', newline='')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(stores)
storelocation_head = []

count = 0
for details in root.findall('store'):
store = []
if count == 0:
    ID = details.find('ID').tag
    storelocation_head.append(ID)
    Name = details.find('Name').tag
    storelocation_head.append(Name)
    postCode = details.find('Postcode').tag
    storelocation_head.append(postCode)
    State = details.find('State').tag
    storelocation_head.append(State)
    csvwriter.writerow(storelocation_head)
    count = count + 1

ID = details.find('ID').text
store.append(ID)
Name = details.find('Name').text
store.append(Name)
PostCode = details.find('Postcode').text
store.append(PostCode)
State = details.find('State').text
store.append(State)
csvwriter.writerow(store)
stores.close()
```

Comment: I suspect that you're using Python 2 because its `open` function doesn't take a `newline` arg. But I think you need to set the [`lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) arg of your CSV Writer to use `\n` rather than the default terminator which is `'\r\n'` .

Comment: If you're on Windows, you need to open the file in `wb` mode to avoid spaces between each line.

Comment: yep you were right thanks guys